# Can I use 2 different Apple IDs with a single install of iTunes?

Tags: itunes, apple-id, iphone

I just got an iPhone 5 at work, and have discovered the only way to get a different ringtone on the device is via iTunes.  However, work will not allow iTunes to be downloaded to Corporate PCs.

I have iTunes at home, and wanted to know if I logged off iTunes with my personal Apple ID and logged in with my work Apple ID, could I add a ringtone to iTunes and then sync it to my work phone.

I have no interest in using any personal music or apps on the work phone, so I don't need/want to authorize media on another device.  I just want to get a darn non-standard ringtone on my iPhone.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can log in with multiple iTunes accounts. Log out of one, log in with the other.

Comment: I've been doing this for years now and it's surprising how well it actually works!

Comment: Wow. So simple lol. Never realized it. Good tip.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Keep in mind that you can authorize an Apple ID for use on only five computers at a time.

Comment: Perhaps this could be improved a little? Could you explain a little more the process of changing accounts in iTunes and such. While this answers the question directly, I think a little more explanation for future visitors would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. See [How to use multiple iPhone, iPad, or iPod devices with one computer](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201572):

*Windows users*

Look in your computer's Help documentation to learn how to set up other user accounts. To find this information:

1. Click the Start Menu and click Help or Help and Support.
2. Enter "new user" in the Search field.
3. Press Return.

If you create multiple user accounts on one computer but want the same media to be available in iTunes for all users, you can share music between different accounts on a single computer.

---

You probably want to create separate libraries, see also [this](http://www.imore.com/how-use-multiple-apple-ids-one-computer-and-itunes). It is too long for reposting, but it describes:

1. How to create a new iTunes library.
2. How to switch between iTunes libraries.