# Same Apple ID but want different apps

Tags: itunes, apple-id

I have an iPhone, iPad and iPad mini - all using one single Apple ID and is synced with one iTunes account in my laptop. When I sync my devices all the apps and files go to individual devices. But if don't want to have a particular app, can I delete only in one device but be as is in others?

Answer (score 1):

One option would be the manual selection of apps for each device.[image]

So instead of syncing all apps with all devices, you could select here which apps to install/remove from each device

Answer (score 0):

You can have different app lineups on multiple devices by turning off automatic sync of all apps on one or more of the devices.

Once that is done, just clean off apps you don't want on each device and you should be set.

Comment: Also see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/82857/can-i-use-2-different-apple-ids-with-a-single-install-of-itunes if you really want two I'd rather than one.

Comment: Is it possible to configure iTunes in one laptop with two different Apple ID? How?

Comment: @ram you can have two accounts on the computer or also commingle two AppleID on one iTunes library. The steps depend on OS and how you choose to divide things...